# How to have a list as a JSON key

Tags: json

I would like to have a list be a JSON key:

```json
{
    [1, 2]: ["foo", "bar"]
}
```

However, this is invalid JSON.  How can one have a list be a JSON key?

Comment: See [page 3 of ECMA-404](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf): *"An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. **A name is a string.**"*

Comment: Serialize the list as a `string`, for example: `const key = JSON.stringify([1, 2]); const json = JSON.stringify({ [key]: ["foo", "bar"] });`